# IOS: How to prevent a view from getting opened in all cells

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a rate button. Upon clicking on that button a view containing 5 stars opens. But when I click on rate button of particular cell, particular view opens but some views of other cells also get opens. I want the view containing 5 stars of that particular view only to get opened.

I am attaching the code of that view.

```
cv = [[ASStarRatingView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(190, y-5, 140, 30)]; //creat an instance of your custom view


 cv.tag = indexPath.row ;
 if([delegate.constants.snsrate[indexPath.row] isEqualToString: @"0"])
 {
      cv.hidden=TRUE;
 }
 else
 {
      cv.hidden=FALSE;
 }

 delegate.constants.selected=1;
 [cell addSubview:cv];
```

And my code to close and open the view.

```
-(void)Rate_Comment:(UIButton *)sender
{



    UIButton *b = (UIButton *)sender;

    NSInteger row = b.tag ;

    for(int i=0;i<[delegate.constants.snsrate count];i++)
        delegate.constants.snsrate[i]= @"0";


    delegate.constants.buttontag  = row;

    UITableViewCell *buttonCell = (UITableViewCell *)[b superview];
    UITableView* table = (UITableView *)[buttonCell superview];
    NSIndexPath* pathOfTheCell = [table indexPathForCell:buttonCell];
    delegate.constants.snsIndexPath = pathOfTheCell;
    if(![delegate.constants.user_id isEqualToString:[delegate.constants.snsCreatedBy objectAtIndex:row]])
                {

                    if([[delegate.constants.snstotalrating_count objectAtIndex:row] isEqualToString:@"0"])
                    {

                       if(cv.hidden)
                        {


                            delegate.constants.snsrate[row]= @"1";

                            cv.hidden=FALSE;

                        }
                        else{


                            delegate.constants.snsrate[row]= @"0";

                                cv.hidden=TRUE;
                        }


[streamTable reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[pathOfTheCell] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

           }else
               {
               if(cv.hidden==FALSE)
               cv.hidden=TRUE;

           }
     }
}
```

I am new to IOS. Please if anyone can help it will be much appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I assume every cell has a "rate" button and a target method, like this:

```
// --------------------------------------------------------------------
// Sorry, I'm typing from memory, these code might not be 100% correct
// --------------------------------------------------------------------

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellID = @"cell";

    MyCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellForIdentifier:cellID];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[MyCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID];

        // --------------------------------------------------------
        // Add the method to execute when tapping on a button
        // --------------------------------------------------------
        [cell.btnRate addTarget:self action:@selector(showRateControl:) forControlEvent:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }

    // self.selectedRow should init with -1, since we don't want to show stars
    // for the first row if self.selectedRow defaults to 0
    if(self.selectedRow == indexPath.row)
    {
        cell.starsView.alpha = 1;
        cell.btnRate.alpha = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.starsView.alpha = 0;
        cell.btnRate.alpha = 1;
    }

    return cell;
}

-(void)showRateControl:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *rateButton = (UIButton *)sender;

    // finding the row which the rate button was tapped
    CGPoint rootPoint = [rateButton convertPoint:CGPointZero inView:self.tableView];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:rootPoint];


    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    // here we record the row which the rate button was tapped
    // in a property we declared in the .h file (see below)
    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    self.selectedRow = indexPath.row;

    // refresh just the selected row (you could alternatively use self.tableView reloadData)
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPath:@[indexPath]];
}
```

In your header file, you can declare your selectedRow property like this:

```
...

class MyViewController: UIViewController
{

}

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger selectedRow;

@end
```

In your implementation file's viewDidLoad, don't forget to initialise self.selectedRow to -1:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    ...

    self.selectedRow = -1;
}
```

See if that helps.